# ¿Cómo hacer para mostrar una imagen cacheada mientras se revisa si hay un cambio?

Tags: html5, imagen, cache

¿Hay algún método en HTML5 que muestre la última imagen que se haya leído (con anterioridad) y vaya a buscar al servidor para ver si cambió la imágen? y que además, en el caso de que no se encuentre siga mostrándose la última que se tuvo (tanto en el contexto offline como que se haya caído el servidor o la imágen ya no esté disponible).

Comment: Quizás no he comprendido bien el problema, pero creo que lo que quieres es cosa del navegador y se hace por defecto (sin necesidad de especificar nada)

Comment: Voy a preparar un ejemplo que corra (un mini server en node que demore en contestar) y una mini página que contenga una imágen con una dirección fija. El mini-server devolverá para esa imagen un archivo distinto cada vez y demorará 3 segundos en devolver el archivo. Lo que espero es ver los 3 primeros segundos la imagen cacheada y luego la traída.